# how to fix my home page closing tag is having an error?

Tags: php, html

This form is my home page. After I log in I cant proceed to the home page 
    because of this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\kusina_online\home.php on line 28

```
<?php  
    include('session.php');

    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        header("location: index.php");
 ?>  
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang="en"> 
      <head>  
            <title>Kusina Online</title>  
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-slim.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                 <h3 align="center">Kusina Online</h3>  
                <br /> 
                <b id="welcome">Howdy, <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
                <div class="desc"><b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b></div>
           </div>  
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My dear! Basic... Where is your closing tag ?

Answer (score 2):

PHP is returning this error because you haven't properly ended your if statement. If you did your code would look like the following:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Or if you only need to run one line of code you can format it like below

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
    header("location: index.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can refer it here.

```
<?php          
include('session.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
    header("location: index.php");
}   // you not closing this statement.
?>  
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang="en"> 
  <head>  
        <title>Kusina Online</title>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">  <!--- maybe a typo why would `/` be here.---> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-slim.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br /><br />  
       <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
             <h3 align="center">Kusina Online</h3>  
            <br /> 
            <b id="welcome">Howdy, <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
            <div class="desc"><b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b></div>
       </div>  
  </body>
```

make sure to check every single line

Answer (score 0):

you should put a closing bracket in line 6.

```
<?php          
include('session.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
    header("location: index.php");
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot closing the bracket in line 6 ...

```
<?php  
    include('session.php');

    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        header("location: index.php");
 ?>  
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang="en"> 
      <head>  
            <title>Kusina Online</title>  
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-slim.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                 <h3 align="center">Kusina Online</h3>  
                <br /> 
                <b id="welcome">Howdy, <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
                <div class="desc"><b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b></div>
           </div>  
      </body>
</html>
```